# Why is Firebase's "getRedirectResults()" returning "{user: null}"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently, when the user goes through the Social auth (via redirects), it successfully creates a user under *Firebase Authentication*, but fails to retrieve the Google/Facebook API's data. Perplexed as to how it's failing to retrieve the data when the Auth is successful.

I used to only have the *SignInWithPopup* (which works perfectly fine), but am trying to get *getRedirectResults* to work too (for mobile).

Given the behavior I've been seeing, the problem is most likely with the *getRedirectResults*. Most likely not the social API setup, because otherwise the user would never get created in Authentication.

The following code resides in **componentDidMount** (this is a React.js app):

```
if (this.state.device === 'mobile') {
  firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
    console.log('login successful! Data is:');
    console.log(result);

    if (result.credential) {
      var provider = result.credential.providerId;
      self.handleSocialAuth(provider, result);
    }
  }).catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
}
```

**results** is supposed to contain the user's data, keeps returning:

```
login successful! Data is:
{user: null}
```

I have not deviated from [official docs examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#getRedirectResult), which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Is this happening on mobile devices, the browser, or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()` - is called after the page loads.
Official doc link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Use the below method to retrieve the user that is logged in.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          console.log(user);
});
```

If no user is logged in the `user` will be `null`.

Live example:

```
checkAuthStatus(){
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            this.setState({ btnWithImg: user });

            if(user !== null){
                this.setState({ userIsLoggedIn: true });
                this.props.toggleLogIn();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This answer does nothing to help OPs question

Comment: @KuraiBankusu, read the problem again. After logging in with `getRedirectResults()`, he is trying to get the user that is logged in, but the result is null. If you use the method that I placed above the result will not be null, if the authentication was successful.

Comment: This is a helpful answer to OPs question. Had exactly the same problem and it solved it. Thanks Sergiu.

Comment: Except for the fact that onAuthStateChanged fires on every login/logout. The purpose of `getRedirectResults()` is to be able to write initialisation logic when a new user signs up (as it explicitly states in the docs). It is null for me also.

Comment: this answer seems helpful but its not clear how to receive userCredentials (microsoft token) after the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()` only when user has been authenticated. Example

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    const result = await firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
    assert(result.user, 'user is empty')
  }
});
```

Comment: from the name of function we assumed we receive the result of the redirect ( for good and bad ) ... had no idea it's suppose to be inside `onAuthStateChanged` thanks

Comment: this doesnt work. still null. guessing there is no way to get provider userCredentials after a user is logged in (persist)