# Firebase RealTime database rules to restrict on user id runs in simulator but not in AngularFire

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, angularfire2

If you look at the screenshot you can see that the simulated test passes:

[image: firebase test]

It restricts adding user data to the users node if the uid does not match.

You can see the location is:

```
/users/6OCBYNh3CTammMWrCjX0F003zab2
```

In other words:

```
/users/$uid
```

When I try to do this from code, I get a permission denied error:

```
  private async addNewUserToFirebase(user: firebase.User): Promise<void> {
    console.log('adding user to Firebase', user);

    try {
      const ref = this.db.list('/users');
      await ref.update(user.uid, {email: 'test@test.com'});    
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unable to add user to firebase db', error);
    }
  }
```

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: update at
>   /users/6OCBYNh3CTammMWrCjX0F003zab2 failed: permission_denied

However, if I change the rule to simply

```
".write": "auth != null"
```

then it works. So why is it failing when I try to match the uid?

**NOTE**

I have also tried:

```
     const refAccount = this.db.list('/users');      
     await refAccount.update(`/${user.uid}`, {email: "test@test.com");
```

and get the same error.

I have tried with multiple users from both the simulator and code. The results are consistent.

Yet [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575194/how-to-to-set-firebase-database-rules-to-secure-data-per-user) shows identical rules, and for that OP it works.

Comment: I somewhat suspect this to be a problem with AngularFire. Can you try `firebase.database().ref("users").chikd(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child("email").set("test@test.com")` to see if that works?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the suggestion, but that gives the same error, so it's not AngularFire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this seems to be an issue with `getRedirectResults()`

Further testing has uncovered that this code works (with the rule `userId === auth.id`):

```
this.angularFireAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('users')
    .child(user.uid)
    .child('email')
    .set('test@test.com');
});
```

but this does not, as the user is always null:

```
  this.angularFireAuth.getRedirectResult().then(credential => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref('users')
      .child(credential.user.uid)
      .child('email')
      .set('test@test.com');
  });
```

This still does not explain why sometimes `auth.uid !== null` works.

But it seems I am not the only person with a null user on `getRedirectResults()` as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880369/why-is-firebases-getredirectresults-returning-user-null) and there is an official bug report [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1682)